# Select feature in Google Earth Engine (MODIS)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am looking at a landcover map from MODIS:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD44B');

var visualization = {
  bands: ['Percent_Tree_Cover'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['bbe029', '0a9501', '074b03']
};

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'Percent Tree Cover');

print(dataset);
```

This shows a map, but I am interested in individual years:

[image]

How can I select feature 0 (2000_03_05) or any of the other features (2001_03_05, 2002_03_05, etc) ?
I can't get it to work with feature selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the metadata filter:

```
var land = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD44B")
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterMetadata('system:index', 'equals','2001_03_06');
```

Answer (score 0):

You do that by [filtering](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_filtering) your image collection. Then you might want to turn your collection into a single image by [reducing](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_reducing) it. Like this, for instance:

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD44B')
  .filterDate('2000-03-05', '2000-03-06') // Filter down to a single day
  .first() // Take the first image in the collection

var visualization = {
  bands: ['Percent_Tree_Cover'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['bbe029', '0a9501', '074b03']
};

Map.addLayer(image, visualization, 'Percent Tree Cover');

print(image);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1517b9af7389396bdcc0b6a34aee6a87

Comment: Thanks! Now, how do I get the second, third, etc feature?